# Getting custom fields on Inventory Number via suiteQL

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suiteql

I am trying to get a custom field on the Inventory Number record via suiteQL, but the field is not found.
There is no issue with permissions, the field is store value.
When  I do `SELECT * FROM InventoryNumber` I don't get any custom fields.